# change slideToggle() behaviour to display:inline-block instead of display:block?

Tags: jquery, css, slidetoggle

my target [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) div needs to be `display:inline-block` instead of `display:block` when it's open. Is there a way to change the jquery behavior here?

Edit:

i'm using jQuery 1.7.0 at the moment. Also, the `<div>` is initially at `display:none` and should expand to `display:inline-block` after a click on a link; but apparently the default state for slideToggle() in this situation is `display:block` ...

Answer (score 63, accepted):

*A little birdie told me...*

```
$('#my-block').slideToggle('medium', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':visible'))
        $(this).css('display','inline-block');
});
```

Comment: `$('#my-block').slideToggle('medium', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':visible'))
        $('this').css('display','inline-block');
});`

Minor edit.

Comment: Actually, it's easier to set CSS for _#element_ as `display: inline-block;` (in <style> block or style sheet) and `display: none;` as style attribute of field. Then, when it toggles to visible it just takes default style defined

Comment: I know this is pretty necro but could someone explain @K.Weber's comment in a little more depth?

Comment: It means use `display:none` as inline style attribute, this is, `<div id="to_toggle" style="display:none">` and set a default style in css stylesheet (`display:inline-block`), this way, `.slideToggle()`, when the element turns visible, will take default style defined in stylesheet (`display:inline-block`)

Comment: @K.Weber This doesn't work once DOM (modal window, for instance), has been closed with fadeToggle

Comment: this didn't work for me, but the solution in @K.Weber's comment worked, wonder if it's cross-browser

Comment: Your method may result a little jump for inside elements. try to add display:none in the inline style block (not in the css file). for example :
<div class="toggle" style="display:none">your content</div>
now slideToggle works find ;)

Answer (score 15):

Just try to hide your block via scripts (dont `display:none` via styles)

HTML

```
<div class="ib">inline-block</div> <a href="#" class="toggle">toggle this</a>
```

CSS

```
.ib{
    display:inline-block;
    background:red;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$(".ib").hide();
$(".toggle").bind("click", function(){
    $(".ib").slideToggle();
    return false;
})
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/fliptheweb/pqrdS/)

Comment: I really like this answer best, the only issue that I had was using an ID instead of a Class. .hide() works great with classes though! Thank you!

Answer (score 14):

I needed the *display:flex* for reordering elements with the *order* property.
Changing to *display:flex* worked but it had to wait for the animation to complete to rearrange the elements, so there was a moment where everything looked clearly disordered.

What did the trick for me was using the start option ([see doc](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/#slideToggle-options)):

```
$("your-selector").slideToggle({
  duration: 200,
  easing: "easeOutQuad",
  start: function() {
    jQuery(this).css('display','flex');
  }
});
```

Comment: This worked great for me, although there is a little bit of a content-jump just before the opening animation finishes. Much more desirable than having all my slides animate closed on page load though, +1!

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you for this!

Comment: @AbrahamBrookes inside content may jump unless you add display:none in the inline style block (not in the css file). for example :
<div class="toggle" style="display:none">your content</div>
now slideToggle works find ;)

Answer (score 4):

If you find yourself seeing an unwanted "Flash of Unstyled Content" you could also use an inline style. The usual wisdom of "don't put style inline" is really meant for your main styling, not for visual effects (JS effects all just add inline styles after all).

Of course, the content won't be seen by JS-disabled search engine spiders, if that's important. If it's not important, you're good!

Update of @fliptheweb's fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GregP/pqrdS/3/

Answer (score 2):

Are you on an old version of jQuery? This should have been fixed already, see discussion here:

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/2185

Comment: Thanks, but i don't think this bug applies here - see my edit.

Comment: I see. In that case, I recommend @fliptheweb's solution

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following trick. It will allow you to use a class for "hidden" while avoiding any flashes due to layout change happening prematurely or belatedly.

(using display:flex with direction:row to make it clear that it's displayed as flex and not as block)

```js
function toggle() {
  let elem = $(".component")
  if (elem.hasClass("hidden")) {
    elem.css("display", "none");
    elem.removeClass("hidden");
  }
  elem.slideToggle(200);
}
```

```css
.component {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="toggle" onclick="toggle();">toggle this</a>
<div class="component hidden">
  <div>item1</div>
  <div>item2</div>
</div>
```