# Using jQuery's slideDown with display: inline-block

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidedown

How can I use jQuery's `slideDown` with `display: inline-block`, as opposed to the default `display: block;`

Some of the content inside the div I'm using requires it to be so, and the design partly breaks unless I fix it. However, fixing it after the sliding down has finished will be glitchy.

Any ideas?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8144944/change-slidetoggle-behaviour-to-displayinline-block-instead-of-displayblock

Comment: Thanks, didn't find that while searching.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should probably wrap the div with `display: inline-block`, into another div, with simple `display: none`, that will be the target of your slideDown function.
I made up a demo for you here http://jsfiddle.net/d3BHL/2/
Let me know if it helps

Comment: Thanks, that's what I ended up doing (only, with CSS3)

Comment: This fiddle is broken. The display styles should be the other way around: container should be inline, and the inside div should be display none.