# How to keep <a href> element with a class tied to javascript from acting as a block element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to format an inline navigation, but the last link which has a class tied to a piece of javascript seems to be causing the entire link to become a block element rather than putting it inline with the rest of the links in the navigation.

I tried removing the class, changing the class to something else (not tied to any script) and it puts the link back in line, which is what leads me to believe it has something to do with the javascript it's tied to. I've also tried calling `a.show` in css to display it inline and inline-block to no avail. I feel like I'm missing a well know rule of thumb.

The `<a href="#" class="show">` is on Line 20 and the `<script>` tag is on Line 25 of the HTML

CSS

```
#nameTag {
  max-width: 800px;
  min-width: 320px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 1px hsla(0,0%,0%,0.72);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 1px hsla(0,0%,0%,0.72);
  border-radius: 43px;
  border: 2px solid #4B4949;
}

#tagTop{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display:block;
  color: #fff;
  font-size:30px;
  text-align: center;
  border-top-left-radius: 40px;
  border-top-right-radius: 40px;
  background-color: #0033AA;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
#tagBottom{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 40px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 40px;
  background-color: #0033AA;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
#tagBottom > a:link, a:visited{
  color:#fff;   
}
#container{
  padding:20px  
}
.miniNav{
  text-align:center;
  font-size:18px;
  font-weight:600;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
.miniNav a:link,a:visited{
  color:#0033AA;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.miniNav a:hover,a:active{
   color:#000;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="nameTag">
 <div id="tagTop">
    <h3>HELLO</h3>
    my name is
</div>
<div id="name">
    <div class="show">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/name.jpg" width="100%" alt="First slide image" class="center-block"></a>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="container">
    <div class="miniNav">
        <a href="#" class="toggle">Change Font</a>​
            &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="documents/EvanGrabenstein_graphicCV.pdf" target="_blank">Download Graphic CV</a>​
            &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="documents/EvanGrabenstein_typedCV.pdf" target="_blank">Download Typed CV</a>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a class="show" href="#">Close CV</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="tagBottom">
</div>
<script>
$("#container").hide();
 $(".show").click(function() {
  $("#container").slideToggle("slow");
});
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: Attaching an event handler to the link doesn't change its display mode. Are you sure you don't have a CSS selector called `.show` elsewhere that's affecting it? For instance you have a div with class `show` above (the JS will attach to that too btw)

Comment: Looks like there's a lot of irrelevant code

Comment: [I can't reproduce the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/L3abruqt/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### UPDATE2

In order to prevent the jerking behavior when clicking the `.hide` and `.show` links, simply add `event.preventDefault()` to your jQuery function.

```
<script>
$("#container").hide();
 $(".show, .hide").click(function(event) { // Pass the event object here
     event.preventDefault();              // Then use the preventDefault() property
  $("#container").slideToggle("slow");
});
</script>
```

#### UPDATE

I misunderstood what the question was, I believe that you wanted the toggle image inline with the other anchors. That would be more trouble than what it's worth. `.show` is in another div and nested. So just add an identical img inside `.miniNav` and make sure the other image disappears. Also, I used a `background-image` for the one inside `.miniNav` because it's easier to handle as a link. It's better if you look at the jQuery than for me to explain it. I also changed the "Close CV" link's class to `.hide` so it doesn't share styles and then added `.hide` to the jQuery in order to keep functionality.

The last link "Close CV" is ok as long as your `#nameTag` is @ 550px wide, else the link will naturally wrap to the next line if less than 550px. If you make `.miniNav` and the anchors behave like table components, there will be no wrapping to the next line. Add `display:table-row` to `.miniNav` and `display:table-cell` to each anchor.

Changed padding so that links conform when `#nameTag` is compact. Removed `&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;` and added `border-right: 1px solid blue;`. To center the links, `margin: 0 auto; display: table;` was added to `#container`.

You could use percentages or ems instead of px for margins and padding so that your text will stay on one line consistently. That takes some experimenting so I'll leave you that to decide.

BTW, when designating selectors in CSS, if you have multiple selectors that apply to a ruleset, you need to be specific on each one.

#### Example

```
 .miniNav a:hover,
  a:active {
     color: #000;
  }
```

> Anchors that are descendants of `.mini-nav` are black when hovered over / **Any** anchor that is active is black.

```
   .miniNav a:hover,
   .miniNav a:active {
        color: #000;
   }
```

> Anchors that are descendants of `.mini-nav` are black when hovered over or is active.

#### Changes

```
#container {
  padding: 10px 0px 15px 7px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
}
.miniNav {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: table-row;
}
.miniNav a,
.miniNav a:link,
.miniNav a:visited {
  color: #0033AA;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: table-cell;
  border-right: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 0 7px;
}
...
.miniNav a:last-of-type {
  border-right: 0px none transparent;
}
```

#### SNIPPET

```js
$("#container").hide();
$(".show, .hide").click(function() {
  $('.show').toggle();
  $("#container").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

```css
#nameTag {
  max-width: 800px;
  min-width: 550px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 1px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.72);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 1px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.72);
  border-radius: 43px;
  border: 2px solid #4B4949;
}
#tagTop {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border-top-left-radius: 40px;
  border-top-right-radius: 40px;
  background-color: #0033AA;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
#tagBottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 40px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 40px;
  background-color: #0033AA;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
#tagBottom > a:link,
a:visited {
  color: #fff;
}
#container {
  padding: 10px 0px 15px 7px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
}
.miniNav {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 0px auto 10px;
  display: table-row;
}
.miniNav a,
.miniNav a:link,
.miniNav a:visited {
  color: #0033AA;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: table-cell;
  border-right: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 0 7px;
}
.miniNav a:hover,
.miniNav a:active {
  color: #000;
}
.miniNav a:last-of-type {
  border-right: 0px none transparent;
}
a.img {
  background: url(http://placehold.it/80x50/eea/e00?text=First=slide+image)no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="nameTag">
  <div id="tagTop">
    <h3>HELLO</h3>
    my name is
  </div>
  <div id="name">
    <div class="show">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/name.jpg" width="100%" alt="First slide image" class="center-block">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="container">

    <div class="miniNav">
      <a href="#" class='img'>First slide image</a>

      <a href="#" class="toggle">Change Font</a>​
      <a href="documents/EvanGrabenstein_graphicCV.pdf" target="_blank">Download Graphic CV</a>​
      <a href="documents/EvanGrabenstein_typedCV.pdf" target="_blank">Download Typed CV</a>

      <a class="hide" href="#">Close CV</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="tagBottom">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks zer00ne. That did the trick. Funny since divs came along, using tables, div or otherwise, has always been the furthest from my mind. 
http://www.evangportfolio.com is the finished product.
Thanks again for the help.

Comment: You are very welcome, sir. Yeah, I started developing when tables for layout was beginning to become taboo, but no one was really using the `display: table-*` properties much and seem to be content struggling with divs. Your name tag layout is clever, there's one more thing to consider is the sudden jerking when a link is clicked, see update 2.

Answer (score 0):

It appears jQuery's `slideToggle()` function defaults to `display:block`, so you can use a callback to set it to `display: inline-block` manually, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10016488/1335537) from user [black](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1313481/black).

Your code would then be:

```
$("#container").hide();
$(".show").click(function() {
    $("#container").slideToggle("slow", function() {
        if ($("#container").is(':visible'))
            $("#container").css('display','inline-block'); 
    });
});
```

You'll also need to style your container as `display: inline-block`, unless I'm misunderstanding your question.

Comment: But `slideToggle` is not being used on any links. The `#container`, a `<div>`, is going to be `block` by default anyway.

Comment: You're right, I was under the assumption that he wanted the entire container to be `display: inline-block`, as the links were not being set to `display:block` when I recreated. @evan-grabenstein can you clarify your desired functionality?