# Use jQuery animations without display: block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to use `.slideToggle()` to toggle a div with `display: none` to `display: grid`. However this animation seems to add `display: block` inline to the html and overwrite any other css class

CSS

```
.grid {
    display: grid;
}
```

jQuery

```
$('#nav-toggle').click(function() {
    $('.nav-menu').slideToggle(500, function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('grid')
    });
});
```

I had somewhat brief success using

```js
$('#nav-toggle').click(function() {
    $('.nav-menu').slideToggle(500, function() {
         if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
             $(this).css('display','grid');
         }
    });
});
```

```css
.nav-menu {
    display: none;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=nav-toggle>
    Toggle
</div>

<div class=nav-menu>
    <div>Item 1</div>
    <div>Item 2</div>
    <div>Item 3</div>
</div>
```

but the initial animation seems to play using `display: block` and once the animation is finished I guess jQuery then sees the element as visible and the HTML snaps from `display: block` (items stacked) to `display: grid` (items spaced).

All following animations seem to play nicely with `display: grid`.

How can I get the initial animation to display correctly too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in order to make responsive CSS media queries much cleaner and easier, I ended up wrapping the `nav` element in a div and simply having the div toggle between `display: none` and `display: block`.

I am still able to align the menu items within since the child of the block is the `nav` which kept the grid property. Also in my case this block was a child of a more complex `display: grid` layout, but since it is still a child, I could still use the CSS grid properties on it, I just had to use older CSS methods to expand and center the block.

Its not perfectly clean but I guess its the best I can do until jQuery is updated to support more than just `display: block` for its animations.

```js
$('#nav-toggle').click(function() {
    $('.nav-menu-container').slideToggle(500, function() {
        if ($(this).css('display') == 'none') {
            $(this).css('display', '');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.nav-menu-container {
    display: none;
}

.nav-menu {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=nav-toggle>
    Toggle
</div>
<div class=nav-menu-container>
    <div class=nav-menu>
        <div>Item 1</div>
        <div>Item 2</div>
        <div>Item 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to set nav-menu to `display:grid;` and to hide and show it with JQuery. By the way if you have a user who disabled JavaScript, he will still be able to read your page.

Try the following code:

```js
$('.nav-menu').hide(); // clearer than display none
$('#nav-toggle').click(function() {
  $('.nav-menu').slideToggle(500, function() {
    if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
      $(this).show(); // clearer than display previous (here grid)
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.nav-menu {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav-toggle">
  Toggle
</div>

<div class="nav-menu">
  <div>Item 1</div>
  <div>Item 2</div>
  <div>Item 3</div>
</div>
```

Related to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8144998/1248177

Comment: Thanks. Hmm this really makes responsive webpages a pain to implement, I guess I will look into other ways to display my menu.

Comment: @myol you may want to use a framework like bootstrap to help you. Beside, did this fix you problem? If so, upvote and accept it. :)

Comment: It didn't fix my problem per-se but I've upvoted anyway since you took the time to answer.